# How does Redis's MGET with one key compared to GET in terms of performance?

Tags: redis

Obviously MGET outperforms GET for batch fetching but is there any pragmatic advantage to using GET instead of MGET when fetching just one key?

For example, when implementing a batch fetching system, is it worthwhile to special-case:

```js
if (keys.length === 1) {
  results = [redis.get(keys[0])];
} else {
  results = redis.mget(keys);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [loop get vs mget, Is there any performance difference in redis lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221077/loop-get-vs-mget-is-there-any-performance-difference-in-redis-lua)

Comment: You need to compare a `MGET` of n keys with `n` GET.  For `n = 1` I would expect GET to be faster as you avoid the overhead of encoding a list, on the wire data, and decoding of the list on the client side.  At some point MGET will be faster overall, however, the end-to-end latency will be smaller for some of initial keys obtained with GET.

Comment: It seems this is not a duplicate question. This question focuses on MGET with 1 key, while that one focuses on MGET with multiple keys.

Comment: One could also run `redis-benchmark get foo` vs `redis-benchmark mget foo` for a quick affirmation. Intuitively, I'd say get is faster (shorter processing code path).

Comment: Yes, this is not a duplicate question. Obviously MGET is better for batches of keys. This question's context is when there is just one key.

Comment: @ide Since you updated the question, check the update of my answer.

Comment: The end-to-end latency will be smaller for the initial GET. But when we are talking about a Redis instance where there is a latency of 100MS on the connection, using MGET should in theory result in an even higher exponential increase. Of course still dependent on the numbe of connections you intend to use.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to get one key, there's no need to call `MGET`, and **`GET` should be a better choice**.

- With `MGET`, Redis replies with an array reply, which costs some more CPU time, i.e. appending array length (in this case, 1), to the reply, and transmitting more data on the wire, i.e. the size of array. Although, normally these cost is negligible, the less work, the better.
- With `MGET`, client library normally returns an array, and you need to get the reply from the array with an index, and make the client code less elegant.
- `MGET` and `GET` behaves differently if key type is NOT STRING. In this case, `MGET` returns nil reply, while `GET` returns an error reply. Normally, in this case, an error reply is better. So that the client can distinguish a non-exist key and a key with wrong type.

**UPDATE**

Since OP updated the question, I update the answer:

> when implementing a batch fetching system, is it worthwhile to special-case

In this case, I don't think it's worthwhile, unless your benchmark shows that `GET` is much faster than `MGET`, and your code hits `if (keys.length === 1)` branch frequently.

As I mentioned above `MGET` and `GET` have different behaviors, if you use both commands, you might also need to do error handling differently, which makes the code more complex. Also such a condition branch make the code less elegant.

In a word, do a benchmark with your dataset, and keep the code simple, unless the optimization significantly improve the performance.